# Get triangular shapes placed in between inline-block boxes, either in front of or on top of

Tags: javascript, html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm currently working on a project where I try to create a more interactive sharepoint portal for the project.

I'm running into a problem where I can't figure out how to position the triangles. Ideally I want them to be placed in between the inline-block boxes. As it seemed easier I have tried to get the triangles above the inline-boxes but I haven't successfully placed them where they're supposed to be. My current version is that I have made white boxes the length of the grey boxes above the grey boxes, but it didn't work out.

Any idea how I can get them placed how I want to? I want them placed like this: [image: what i want it do] I'm sorry if the code is a bit chaotic, I'm new to CSS/HTML and want to learn. I'm aware that the boxes go over two lines here in stackoverflow, but in sharepoint it looks good.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .oransjboks {
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 0.3em;
      padding-bottom: 0.3em;
      padding-right: 0.3em;
      padding-left: 0.3em;
      margin-bottom: 0.3em;
      background-color: #F8992E;
      height: 25px;
    }

    .nextto {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 0.3em;
      padding-bottom: 0.3em;
      padding-right: 0.3em;
      padding-left: 0.3em;
      background-color: #D0CEC4;
      height: 60px;
      width: 15.66%;
      vertical-align: top;
    }

    .nextto .bottom {
      text-align: left;
      min-width: 200px;
      top: 40px;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
      padding: 10px 20px;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background-color: #767171;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 14px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 99999999;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: none;
    }

    .nextto:hover .bottom {
      display: block;
    }

    .nextto .bottom i {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -12px;
      width: 24px;
      height: 12px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .nextto .bottom i::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 50%) rotate(45deg);
      background-color: #767171;
    }

    .hvitBoks {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-top: 0.3em;
      padding-bottom: 0.3em;
      padding-right: 0.3em;
      padding-left: 0.3em;
      height: 60px;
      width: 7%;
      vertical-align: top;
    }

    .nextto:hover {
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #767171;
    }

    .triangle {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 100px 50px 0 50px;
      border-color: #00a76d transparent transparent transparent;
    }

    .triangle tekst {
      position: relative;
      color: #ffffff;
      top: -75px;
      left: -15px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }

    .triangle tekst2 {
      position: relative;
      color: #ffffff;
      top: -75px;
      left: -20px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width:100%">
    <div class="oransjboks"><b>Step 1.1 Detail design</div>
  </div>
  <!-- <div style="width:100%"> -->
  <div style="width:100%">
    <div class="hvitBoks"> </div>
    <div class="hvitBoks"> </div>
    <div class="triangle">
      <tekst> QL1 <tekst>
    </div>
    <div class="hvitBoks"> </div>
    <div class="triangle">
      <tekst> QL2 <tekst>
    </div>
    <div class="hvitBoks"> </div>
    <div class="triangle">
      <tekst> QL3 <tekst>
    </div>
    <div class="hvitBoks"> </div>
    <div class="triangle">
      <tekst2> QL4H <tekst2>
    </div>
    <div class="hvitBoks"> </div>
    <div class="triangle">
      <tekst> QL4 <tekst>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="width:100%">
    <div class="nextto"><b>Step 1.1.0 <br> some text
        <div class="bottom">
          <h3>Engineering objectives</h3>
          text
          <i></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nextto"><b>Step 1.1.1 <br> some text
        <div class="bottom">
          <h3>Engineering objectives</h3>
          more text
          <i></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nextto"><b>Step 1.1.2 <br> text about this step
        <div class="bottom">
          <h3>Engineering objectives</h3>
          text
          <i></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nextto"><b>Step 1.1.3 <br> and this
        <div class="bottom">
          <h3>Engineering objectives</h3>
          text
          <i></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nextto"><b>Step 1.1.4H <br> interesting step
        <div class="bottom">
          <h3>Engineering objectives</h3>
          text
          <i></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nextto"><b>Step 1.1.4 <br> wow almost done, good job
        <div class="bottom">
          <h3>Engineering objectives</h3>
        text
          <i></i>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should close all `b` tags. I have changed your HTML structure and also the CSS. Too many changes to mention here.

```css
.oransjboks {
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 0.3em;
      padding-bottom: 0.3em;
      padding-right: 0.3em;
      padding-left: 0.3em;
      margin-bottom: 0.3em;
      background-color: #F8992E;
      height: 25px;
    }

    .nextto {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 0.3em;
      padding-bottom: 0.3em;
      /*padding-right: 0.3em;
      padding-left: 0.3em;
      background-color: #D0CEC4;*/
      height: 90px;
      /*width: 15.66%;*/
      vertical-align: top;
      flex: 1;
      position: relative;
    }

    .nextto .bottom {
      text-align: left;
      /*min-width: 200px;*/
      top: 110px;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
      padding: 10px 20px;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background-color: #767171;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 14px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 99999999;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: none;
    }

    .nextto:hover .bottom {
      display: block;
    }

    .nextto .bottom i {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -12px;
      width: 24px;
      height: 12px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .nextto .bottom i::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 50%) rotate(45deg);
      background-color: #767171;
    }

    .hvitBoks {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-top: 0.3em;
      padding-bottom: 0.3em;
      padding-right: 0.3em;
      padding-left: 0.3em;
      height: 60px;
      width: 7%;
      vertical-align: top;
    }

    .nextto:hover {
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #767171;
    }

    .triangle {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 100px 50px 0 50px;
      border-color: #00a76d transparent transparent transparent;
    }

    .triangle tekst {
      position: relative;
      color: #ffffff;
      top: -75px;
      left: -15px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }

    .triangle tekst2 {
      position: relative;
      color: #ffffff;
      top: -75px;
      left: -20px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
    .container {
        display: flex;  
        background: #D0CEC4;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

```html
<div class="oransjboks"><b>Step 1.1 Detail design</b></div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="nextto"><b>Step 1.1.0</b> <br> some text
        <div class="bottom">
          <h3>Engineering objectives</h3>
          text
          <i></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nextto"><b>Step 1.1.1</b> <br> some text
        <div class="bottom">
          <h3>Engineering objectives</h3>
          more text
          <i></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle">
      <tekst> QL1 <tekst>
    </div>
    
    <div class="nextto"><b>Step 1.1.2</b> <br> text about this step
        <div class="bottom">
          <h3>Engineering objectives</h3>
          text
          <i></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle">
      <tekst> QL2 <tekst>
    </div>
    
    <div class="nextto"><b>Step 1.1.3</b> <br> and this
        <div class="bottom">
          <h3>Engineering objectives</h3>
          text
          <i></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle">
      <tekst> QL3 <tekst>
    </div>
    
    <div class="nextto"><b>Step 1.1.4H</b> <br> interesting step
        <div class="bottom">
          <h3>Engineering objectives</h3>
          text
          <i></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle">
      <tekst2> QL4H <tekst2>
    </div>
    
    <div class="nextto"><b>Step 1.1.4</b> <br> wow almost done, good job
        <div class="bottom">
          <h3>Engineering objectives</h3>
        text
          <i></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle">
      <tekst> QL4 <tekst>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, that's great, thank you so much :)